# AWS Service Quota: How to get service quota for Amazon S3 using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, service, quota

I get the error *"An error occurred (NoSuchResourceException) when calling the GetServiceQuota operation:"* while trying running the following boto3 python code to get the value of quota for "Buckets"

```
client_quota = boto3.client('service-quotas')
resp_s3 = client_quota.get_service_quota(ServiceCode='s3', QuotaCode='L-89BABEE8')
```

In the above code, QuotaCode "L-89BABEE8" is for "Buckets". I presumed the value of ServiceCode for Amazon S3 would be "s3" so I put it there but I guess that is wrong and throwing error. I tried finding the documentation around ServiceCode for S3 but could not find it. I even tried with "S3" (uppercase 'S' here), "Amazon S3" but that didn't work as well.

What I tried?
`client_quota = boto3.client('service-quotas') resp_s3 = client_quota.get_service_quota(ServiceCode='s3', QuotaCode='L-89BABEE8')`

What I expected?
Output in the below format for S3. Below example is for EC2 which is the output of `resp_ec2 = client_quota.get_service_quota(ServiceCode='ec2', QuotaCode='L-6DA43717')`

Answer (score 1):

I just played around with this and I'm seeing the same thing you are, empty responses from any service quota list or get command for service `s3`. However `s3` is definitely the correct service code, because you see that come back from the service quota `list_services()` call. Then I saw there are also list and get commands for AWS default service quotas, and when I tried that it came back with data. I'm not entirely sure, but based on the docs I think any quota that can't be adjusted, and possibly any quota your account hasn't requested an adjustment for, will probably come back with an empty response from `get_service_quota()` and you'll need to run `get_aws_default_service_quota()` instead.

So I believe what you need to do is probably run this first:

```
client_quota.get_service_quota(ServiceCode='s3', QuotaCode='L-89BABEE8')
```

And if that throws an exception, then run the following:

```
client_quota.get_aws_default_service_quota(ServiceCode='s3', QuotaCode='L-89BABEE8')
```

Comment: Mark, Thanks so much for shedding the light! you're right I was getting error as there was no "applied quota value" for the quota code 'L-89BABEE8' for S3. When I changed the method from "get_service_quota" to 'get_aws_default_service_quota", it worked. 

Just to clarify, client_quota.get_service_quota(ServiceCode='s3', QuotaCode='L-89BABEE8') errors out with the error message "NoSuchResourceException"; it does not return empty.

Comment: I was testing with the CLI tool, which was coming back empty. I've updated my answer.